# Conditionally query for iterating a list using ibatis

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I'm using the below query in ibatis for iterating through a list. I want to add a condition incase the list is empty. In this case i want to change the condition.PFB the query in xml:

```
   <statement id="getSearchLateJob" parameterClass="map" resultMap="getCurrentJob_r">
  select a.JOBSET as "JOBSET",
    a.JOB as "JOB",
    a.JOB_NO as "JOB_NO",
    a.QUALIFIER as "QUALIFIER",
    case when year(a.START_TIME) = 1900 then null else a.START_TIME end as "EXPECTED_START_TIME",
    case when year(a.END_TIME) = 1900 then null else a.END_TIME end as "END_TIME",
    datediff(mi,a.START_TIME,a.END_TIME) as "DURATION",
    b.JOB_AVG as "JOB_AVG",
    a.STATUS as "STATUS" 
from  CA_JOB_STATUS a,JOB_AVG b
where a.JOBSET = b.JOBSET
    and a.JOB=b.JOB
    and a.JOBSET like #jobSet:VARCHAR#
    and a.JOB like #job:VARCHAR#    
    <!-- and a.STATUS in -->
    <dynamic prepend="and a.STATUS in ">
    <iterate property= "currentJobStatusArr"  open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
    #currentJobStatusArr[]:VARCHAR#
    </iterate>
    </dynamic>
order by a.END_TIME desc, a.START_TIME desc
```

In this case, how can i change the dynamic prepend where it iterates a list and builds an IN query, to a like query: Something like this:

Change from:

```
    select * from table where status in (?,?)
```

To:

```
    select * from table where status like ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    <dynamic prepend="and a.STATUS ">
            <isNotEmpty property="currentJobStatusArr">
                <iterate property= "currentJobStatusArr" open="in (" close=")" conjunction=",">
                 #currentJobStatusArr[]:VARCHAR#
                </iterate>
            </isNotEmpty>
            <isEmpty property="currentJobStatusArr" >
                like #allRec:VARCHAR#
            </isEmpty>
        </dynamic>
```